# Javascript Object print object value

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to get an value from an object and prit on screen but no success...

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbascg4v/5/

```
app.js
// Função construtora
function KeyDown(e) {
   this.faq = e.keyCode;
    alert(e.keycode)
}

// Prototype com os métodos
KeyDown.prototype = {
   printr: function() {
      alert(this.faq);
   }
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown, true);

index.html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid red"></canvas>

<script>
teste = new KeyDown();
teste.print();

</script>
```

when i push a key on canvas, i want to get the value of my key and put in my object, then i want to print the object and his value.

Comment: JavaScript variables are *case-sensitive*, that means that `e.keycode` and `e.keyCode` are **not** the same (hint: `e.keyCode` is the correct one).

Comment: yea, the first alert was just a try to make if the keycode works, i fixed, and it prints but i will not use the alert there i want to call the print fuction on keydown to print it how can i call the print function and get the value from the attribute to print it ?  i have tried to do teste.print(); but no susscess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer to your question is most likely *you don't need prototyping*:

```
function KeyDown(){
   // Initialize properties
   this.faq = 0;
   this.update = function(e){
       // Set faq
       this.faq = e.keyCode;
   }
   this.print = function(){
       // Alert faq
       alert(this.faq);
   }
}
```

And then:

window.

```
test = new KeyDown();
addEventListener('keydown', test.update, true);
test.print(); // Will alert 0
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbascg4v/8/)

Comment: oh thanks about that, but i still cant make it working http://jsfiddle.net/Lbascg4v/7/

Comment: @user1748153 checkout the link I added. The issue was that the JS script  needs to be loaded before the body.

Comment: thank u so much ! i will try to figure out how to update with the keyvalues :D